# Wordpress multiple wp_querys, wp_reset_postdata() not working

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I'm trying to run two loops on a page. After the first loop runs, it completely stops the second loop. I looked into it and read up on wp_reset_postdata() and wp_reset_query(), neither of which have helped me so far.

My first loop looks like this:

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'agents'                         
);

$posts = new WP_Query($args);

if( $posts->have_posts() ): while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post(); ?>

    <wordpress post here>

<?php

endwhile; 

wp_reset_postdata();

endif;

?>
```

A little ways down the page, we get the loop that isn't working due to the first loop:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'properties',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'property_types' => $page,
    'property_cities' => $urlCity,
    'meta_key' => 'select-agent-value',
    'meta_value' => $agentId,
    's' => $urlAddress                              
);

$posts = new WP_Query($args);

if( $posts->have_posts() ): while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post();

    <wordpress post here>

endwhile; 

wp_reset_postdata();

endif;
```

The arguments in the second loop are from this code that runs a little before it:

```
$page = $_GET['property-type'];
$urlCity = $_GET['city'];
$urlAddress = $_GET['address'];
$agentId = $_GET['agentId'];

if ($page == 'all') {
    $page = '';
}                           

if ($urlCity == 'all') {
    $urlCity = '';
}

if ($agentId == 'all') {
    $agentId = '';
}
```

I get the feeling it could something simple I'm missing. Appreciate any help anyone can give!

Comment: So I found out the argument in the second loop "'property_types' => $page," is what's causing the loop to not run. When there is a specific value there in place of the variable, the loop actually runs just fine. With this information, I am working to figure out a solution!

Comment: What I've found is the value being stored in the $page variable, which is coming from $_GET, is the integer 1. Just that. And its only doing that if I have the first loop running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I figured out the issue, it ultimately had nothing to do with resetting the query as I originally felt. What was happening was in the second loop, where I set 'property_types' => $page, that variable value was from a $_GET used earlier on the page. For whatever reason, the first loop was taking that variable and changing its value, which eventually effected the second loop. So I basically just redid the $_GET after the first loop, which made sure the right value was stored in the variable.

Thanks for anyone who might have been looking over it and trying to figure out how to help. I was kinda blind sided by what the actual problem was which ultimately made it hard to help since I actually had no clue what was actually happening.

Comment: hey Austin, I am sort of having the same issue but I am not taking any user input, could you take a look at my code and see whats up? Thanks man https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53910555/unable-to-reset-post-data-in-wordpress-custom-query