# Unable to reset post data in wordpress custom query

Tags: wordpress

Edit - I already tried `wp_reset_query()` it doesn't work, the first loop executes as intended but the second loop just jumps to the `else` and I get `not working`
I am using 2 custom `WP_Query` loops in one page, the first is to get posts from a certain category, and the second is just getting the posts by dates,

here's the code

```
            <?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'post_status' => 'any',
                'category' => 3,
                'posts_per_page' => 4);
            $wpdb = new WP_Query($args);
            if ($wpdb->have_posts()):
                while ($wpdb->have_posts()):
                    $wpdb->the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="patta p-4 col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                        <!-- FIX THIS -->
                        <img class="card-img-top"
                             src="<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>"
                             alt="<?php the_post_thumbnail_caption() ?>"/>
                        <h4><b><?php the_title(); ?></b><br></h4>
                        <p>
                            <a href="#">Link</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                <?php
                endwhile;
                wp_reset_postdata();
            endif;
            ?>
```

second loop

```
<?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'post_status' => 'any',
                'orderby' => 'post_date',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'posts_per_page' => 4);
            $wpdb = new WP_Query($args);
            if ($wpdb->have_posts()):
                while ($wpdb->have_posts()):
                    $wpdb->the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="patta p-4 col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                        <!-- FIX THIS -->
                        <img class="card-img-top"
                             src="<?php if (the_post_thumbnail()): the_post_thumbnail(); else:echo 'https://lamasec.pythonanywhere.com/static/img/vulnhub.png';endif; ?>"
                             alt="<?php the_post_thumbnail_caption() ?>"/>
                        <h4><b><?php the_title(); ?></b><br></h4>
                        <p>
                            <a href="#">Link</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                <?php
                endwhile;
                wp_reset_postdata();
                else: echo 'not working';
            endif;
            ?>
```

I am using `wp_reset_postdata();` but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the documentation for multiple loops in one page [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Multiple_Loops_in_Action), I only had one `WP_Query` for both the loops. I stored the ID's of all the posts from the desired category and check for them in the second loop and `continue` over them. Here's the final code -

first loop

```
        <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'any',
            'category' => 3,
            'posts_per_page' => 4);
        $wpdb = new WP_Query($args);
        if ($wpdb->have_posts()):
        while ($wpdb->have_posts()):
            $wpdb->the_post();
            $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; ?>
            <div class="patta p-4 col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                <!-- FIX THIS -->
                <img class="card-img-top"
                     src="<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>"
                     alt="<?php the_post_thumbnail_caption() ?>"/>
                <h4><b><?php the_title(); ?></b><br></h4>
                <p>
                    <a href="#">Link</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Second Loop

```
if (have_posts()):
                while (have_posts()):
                    the_post();
                    if (in_array($post->ID, $do_not_duplicate)) continue;
                    ?>
                    <div class="patta p-4 col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                        <!-- FIX THIS -->
                        <img class="card-img-top"
                             src="<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>"
                             alt="<?php the_post_thumbnail_caption() ?>"/>
                        <h4><b><?php the_title(); ?></b><br></h4>
                        <p>
                            <a href="#">Link</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                <?php
                endwhile;
                endif;
            endif;
            ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should also use:
`wp_reset_query()`

Comment: I already tried that, it doesn't work. The first loop executes and outputs the blogs title and whatever content I desire however the second loop just executes the Else statement and I get `not working`

Comment: Thanks for this, wp_reset_postdata didn't work with multiple loops in single.php and this solved it after adding after first loop